# Can't create a pandas data frame in Pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have been using Pyspark (which I have setup locally on my machine) to query a large data set, which has worked well so far. However, I would like to create pandas data frames for some of the data.

```
SummaryStatList = []

for i in dataColumns:
    
    SummaryStatList.append(df.groupby('Status').agg(func.min(df[i]).alias(i + ' Min'),
    func.max(df[i]).alias(i + ' Max'),
    func.mean(df[i]).alias(i + ' Mean'),
    func.stddev(df[i]).alias(i + ' Variance'),
    func.percentile_approx(i,0.5).alias(i + ' Median')))
    

dfSummaryStat = pd.DataFrame(SummaryStatList)
```

But upon creating a pandas data frame I get this error:

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\Homework\UniCS\CS Year 3\Big Data\.env_BigData\BigDataAssingment.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pyspark.sql.pandas._typing import PandasDataFrame
ImportError: cannot import name 'PandasDataFrame' from 'pyspark.sql.pandas._typing' (unknown location)
```

These are the imported libraries:

```
import os
import findspark
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.pandas._typing import PandasDataFrame
import seaborn
import numpy as np
import sklearn
from pyspark.ml.feature import Imputer
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sc = SparkContext("local", "Big Data Assignment") 
sql = SQLContext(sc)
import pyspark.sql.functions as func 
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
```

Now getting this error:

```
f:\Homework\UniCS\CS Year 3\Big Data\.env_BigData\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\context.py:77: FutureWarning: Deprecated in 3.0.0. Use SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate() instead.
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\Homework\UniCS\CS Year 3\Big Data\.env_BigData\lib\site-packages\findspark.py", line 143, in init
    py4j = glob(os.path.join(spark_python, "lib", "py4j-*.zip"))[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\Homework\UniCS\CS Year 3\Big Data\.env_BigData\BigDataAssingment.py", line 20, in <module>
    findspark.init()
  File "f:\Homework\UniCS\CS Year 3\Big Data\.env_BigData\lib\site-packages\findspark.py", line 145, in init
    raise Exception(
Exception: Unable to find py4j, your SPARK_HOME may not be configured correctly
```

Have no idea why since it worked before?

Comment: what happens if you remove this line,  `from pyspark.sql.pandas._typing import PandasDataFrame` and do `import pandas as pd`

Comment: @anarchy I do just use import pandas as pd. So no idea what its on about.

Comment: What happens when you just remove that line i mentioned ??

Comment: @anarchy yeah i think that worked now I've just got another error lol

Comment: Show me the new error please

Comment: @anarchy how do i just send you the error?

Comment: Post it in the question, add an update or edit at the bottom section

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
wget -q https://downloads.apache.org/spark/spark-3.0.1/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz
```

or manually download it, then unzip it, then add the following lines to your python file

```
import os 
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "/path/to/file/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop3.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.toPandas()`

```
pandas_df = spark_df.toPandas()
```